# Deleting worksheets with looping

Tags: excel, vba

Could you tell me someone why just every second sheet is deleted, however if I turn off the worksheets.delete line than in the message box appears all the sheet names.

```
Sub tor()
    Dim wsz As Integer

    wsz = Application.Worksheets.Count

    For i = 2 To wsz
        MsgBox Application.Worksheets(i).Name
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.Worksheets(i).Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

What happens is that when you delete a worksheet from the Worksheets collection, the next sheet takes the index of the one you just deleted. You then increment `i`, skipping the next sheet that you actually wanted to delete.

The easiest solution is to delete worksheets beginning from the end.

```
For i = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count To 2 Step -1
    Application.Worksheets(i).Delete
Next i
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete the sheet in reverse. Every time you delete a sheet, the Sheet index gets shifted.

```
Sub tor()
    Dim wsz As Integer, i as Long

    wsz = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For i = wsz To 2 Step -1
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Delete
    Next i

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```