# Selecting specific sheets and saving in new file

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with information on 240 buildings, one sheet for each 1, 2, 3, 4 [..], 239, 240. and then other sheets for new information 1 (1), 1 (2), 1 (3) etc. Is it possible to create a vba that selects 1 (*) and copies only the sheets for building 1 in one file, and so on for all 240 buildings ?

Edit. I know this is not allowed, but the pseudo code would be smth like this

```
for i=1..240
  Pattern = "([i]\s\(\d\))" ' Sheet name 1 (1), 1 (2) etc
  copy in new file
end
```

I'm just not familiar enough with vba.

The sheets are named like this :

```
1, 3, 5, 4, 25, 34, 87, 95, 110, 125, 3 (1), 4 (1), 110 (1), 3 (2), 110 (2), 110 (3)
```

And I need to group them like this :

```
1, 1 (1), 1 (2), 1 (3)
2
3 (1)
110, 110 (1), 110 (2)
...
```

The original naming syntax is like this: #buildingNum[1-240] space (#update)

Comment: You would be better off just deleting the sheets you dont want to include and then using `SaveAs`

Comment: To the person that down voted me, you are perfectly right. Thing is i have a pretty good idea of what i need but not how to write it in vba

Comment: @braX that is what I am doing but it will take days

Comment: Sheet name `like "1 (*"` perhaps?

Comment: Days? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220661/deleting-worksheets-with-looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want. The name of the worksheets will be 1,2,3... sheet names will be 1 (1), 1 (2), 2 (1)... Just change the Key name if you want to name the workbook something else.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim sheetvar As Variant
    Dim mainsheet As String
    Dim subsheets As String
    Dim sheetdict As Object
    Dim currentbook As Workbook

    Set sheetdict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set currentbook = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each sheetvar In currentbook.Sheets
        If InStr(1, sheetvar.Name, "(") Then
            mainsheet = trim(Split(sheetvar.Name, "(")(0))
        Else
            mainsheet = sheetvar.Name 'Get Name
        End If
        If Not sheetdict.exists(mainsheet) Then 'Make Dictionary Key
            subsheets = sheetvar.Name
            sheetdict.Add mainsheet, subsheets
        Else
            subsheets = sheetdict(mainsheet) & "|" & sheetvar.Name
            sheetdict(mainsheet) = subsheets
        End If
    Next sheetvar

    Dim key As Variant
    Dim isheet As Variant
    Dim newbook As Workbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Might not want this if you want to see whats going on
    For Each key In sheetdict
        Set newbook = Workbooks.Add
        newbook.SaveAs key & ".xlsx"
        For Each isheet In Split(sheetdict(key), "|")
            If Not isheet Like "" Then
                currentbook.Sheets(isheet).Copy before:=newbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            End If
        Next isheet
        If newbook.Sheets.Count > 1 Then 'Dodge error if there is only 1 sheet
            newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
        End If
    newbook.save
    newbook.close
    Next key
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. It works but it has selected all the sheets starting by 1, like 10, 176, 126 etc, which are separate buildings. Normally it should group together 118, 118 (1), 118 (2) etc which are the same building

Comment: Didn't think of that, this should do it.

Comment: You are my hero !

Comment: Just one edit, can you change it so it doesnt open the new files. I can not finnish the execution : Run-time error '1004' - The file could not be accessed

Comment: add a newbook.close after the newbook.save, you can turn off application.screenupdating too if you dont want the screen flashing, which should make a it run slightly smoother.

Comment: closing the files and turning screenupdate off made it smoother, but my problem actually came from special characters in the sheet names that couldnt be in file names. Also a hidden sheet stopped the execution. It worked fine after correcting this

Answer (score 1):

I would not attempt this task in one go.  I have seen tasks like this where something was not copied to the new location or copied to the wrong location.  It can be months before the mistake is noticed and undoing any damage caused by the mistake can be expensive or impossible.

Below is the first part of my solution.  It uses an array of collections and allows for up to 250 buildings.  You believe there are 240 buildings but, if there are more, amend `Dim WshtGrps(0 To 250) As Collection`.   It classifies each worksheet and places its name in one of the collections.  If the name does not match your format, it is placed in `WshtGrps(0)`.  Once all worksheets are classified, the collections are output to desktop file “Worksheets.txt”.  With my test workbook, the output is:

```
Grp|Worksheets -->
  0|Other1|Other2|1.2|251|
  1|1|1 (2)|1 (3)|
  2|2|2 (2)|
  3|3|3 (2)|3 (3)|3 (4)|
  4|4|4 (2)|
  5|5|
 10|10|
 11|11|
 12|12|
 20|20|
 30|30|
100|100|
200|200|
250|250|250 (2)|
```

You can see that worksheets with non-standard or out-of-range names appear at the top.  Let us hope you have no row for WshtGrps(0) but, if you do, you will need to decide how to handle them.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SplitWorkbook()

  Dim InxM As Long
  Dim InxW As Long
  Dim Line As String
  Dim NumFile As Long
  Dim NumWsht As Double
  Dim Path As String
  Dim WshtGrps(0 To 250) As Collection

  ' Initialise all the collections
  For InxW = LBound(WshtGrps) To UBound(WshtGrps)
    Set WshtGrps(InxW) = New Collection
  Next

  ' Add the name of all worksheets with integer name N to
  ' WshtGrps(N).  If the name N is not an integer or N is
  ' greater than UBound(WshtGrps) add the name to WshtGrps(0).
  For InxW = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    ' Val() skips any spaces then extracts digits up to the end of the
    ' string or until it reaches a character is does not recognise as
    ' part of a number. It returns zero if no digits are found.
    NumWsht = Val(Worksheets(InxW).Name)
    If NumWsht >= 1 And NumWsht <= UBound(WshtGrps) And CInt(NumWsht) = NumWsht Then
      WshtGrps(NumWsht).Add Worksheets(InxW).Name
    Else
      'NumWsht is out of range or not a integer
      WshtGrps(0).Add Worksheets(InxW).Name
    End If
  Next

  ' Output the worksheet groups to desktop file "Worksheets,txt"
  Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\Worksheets.txt"
  NumFile = FreeFile
  Open Path For Output As #NumFile
  Print #1, "Grp|Worksheets -->"
  For InxW = LBound(WshtGrps) To UBound(WshtGrps)
    If WshtGrps(InxW).Count > 0 Then
      Line = PadL(InxW, 3)
      For InxM = 1 To WshtGrps(InxW).Count
        Line = Line & "|" & WshtGrps(InxW)(InxM)
      Next
      Line = Line & "|"
      Print #1, Line
    End If
  Next
  Close #1

  ' ###### Delete when you are happy with the contents of Worksheets.txt
  Exit Sub

  Const WbkNameRoot As String = "Building "

  Dim InxW2 As Long
  Dim WbkNew As Workbook
  Dim WbkSrc As Workbook

  ' This assumes the worksheets to be copied are in the workbook
  ' containing this macro.  Amend if necessary.
  Set WbkSrc = ThisWorkbook

  ' Amend if you want the new workbooks to be somewhere else
  Path = WbkSrc.Path & "\"

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  For InxW = 1 To UBound(WshtGrps)
    If WshtGrps(InxW).Count > 0 Then
      Set WbkNew = Workbooks.Add

      With WbkNew
        ' Ensure all default worksheet have a name that does not
        ' match sheets to be copied in
        For InxW2 = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
          .Worksheets(InxW2).Name = "Other" & InxW2
        Next

        For InxM = 1 To WshtGrps(InxW).Count
          WbkSrc.Worksheets(WshtGrps(InxW)(InxM)).Copy After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
        Next

        For InxW2 = .Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
          If Left$(.Worksheets(InxW2).Name, 5) = "Other" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .Worksheets(InxW2).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
          End If
        Next

        .SaveAs Filename:=Path & WbkNameRoot & PadL(InxW, 3, "0") & ".xlsx"
        .Close
      End With
    End If
  Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Public Function PadL(ByVal Str As String, ByVal PadLen As Long, _
                     Optional ByVal PadChr As String = " ") As String

  ' Pad Str with leading PadChr to give a total length of PadLen
  ' If the length of Str exceeds PadLen, Str will not be truncated

  '   Sep15 Coded
  ' 20Dec15 Added code so overlength strings are not truncated
  ' 10Jun16 Added PadChr so could pad with characters other than space

  If Len(Str) >= PadLen Then
    ' Do not truncate over length strings
    PadL = Str
  Else
    PadL = Right$(String(PadLen, PadChr) & Str, PadLen)
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: Hi, but I want to create an excel for 1 | 1 (1) | 1 (2) | 1 (3) etc, then another for 2 | 2 (1) | 2 (2), another for 140 | 140 (1) etc. Also in my case sheets weren't grouped in Worksheets.txt

Comment: @alfred  Sorry, I do not understand.  The second row of the list is `  1|Sheet1|Sheet1 (2)|Sheet1 (3)|`.  This means "Sheet1", "Sheet1 (2)" an "Sheet1 (3)" have been identified as group or building 1.  The second part of my routine copies these three worksheets to "Building 001.xlsx".  The second part of my routine should not be run until you have confirmed there are no worksheets in `WshtGrps(0)`.  I will post the second part of my routine in a few minutes.

Comment: I have just realised that I had not read your question carefully enough.  Your worksheets are named "N" not "SheetN".  I see Warcurpine has fixed his solution.  I will finish my solution if his still does not work.

Comment: I can only mark only one as the solution, but please finish yours. I want to understand how you did it

Comment: @alfred  I have included my complete, revised solution.  There is an `Exit Sub` after the first part.  You can run the macro to create the text file without the macro creating any workbooks.  If you want to try the second part, delete the `Exit Sub`.  I do not think Warcupine's solution is very different but I am not a fan of Dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you, I will use both to see if anything is missing

Comment: @alfred.  Wise.  One of my early managers would not accept a proposal unless they were two ways of achieving the same output.  He would have both ways implemented and required the output to be the same.